# Can there be double diminutives in Latin?

Tags: medieval-latin, derivation, scientific-names, diminutive

I've been reading some Latin of the 17th and 18th centuries and am wondering if it is possible for there to be "double diminutives." As I understand it, the word "cerebellum" (Oxford Latin = "brain") is a diminutive of "cerebrum" (also "brain"). But I've found an 18th-century author who coins the term "cerebellula." I know that "-ula" is another diminutive ending, so I'm wondering if it really might be the case that "cerebellula" is a double diminutive, meaning "little little brain" or "tiny brain."

Is this possible, and is there any classic/medieval/Renaissance Latin precedent for this move?

Comment: A popular paper on this topic is Miller's [The Formation of Latin Diminutives of Nouns and Adjectives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323534846_The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives), which points out that there's not really an upper limit on how many diminutives you can stack onto a single word but two is not uncommon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, double diminutives are possible in Latin. I found a few other examples from a search on [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search) of Lewis and Short (I looked for words ending in "llula", "llulus" and "llulum"):

- [arcellula](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Darcellula) < arcella < arca

  > a very little box, Diom. p. 313 P.
- [lamellula](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlamellula) < [lamella](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=lamella&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) < lamina

  > a small plate of metal: “glebulas emi, lamellulas paravi,” Petr. 57, 6.
- [asellulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dasellulus) < [asellus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=asellus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) < asinus

  > a small, young ass, Arn. 3, p. 109.
- [lapillulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlapillulus) < [lapillus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=lapillus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) < lapis

  > a very little stone, gravel-stone (late Lat.), Sol. 10, 12.
- [libellulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlibellulus) < libellus < liber

  > a very little book (post-class.), Mart. Cap. 3, § 289.
- [cultellulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcultellulus) < [cultellus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=cultellus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) < culter

  > a little knife, Sol. 38.
- [agellulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dagellulus) < [agellus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=agellus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) < ager

  > a very small field, Symm. Ep. 2, 30.

There were also other possible examples that I omitted because they were not as clear to me. Unfortunately, I do not have the expertise to explain how these were used.

Comment: Many more examples (with some false positives) are available here: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=llul&lang=la

Comment: So apparently the answer is YES! Very interesting, and great examples.

Answer (score 5):

There certainly are double diminutives in Latin. Here are some examples explicitly indicated in Lewis and Short:

- [*agellulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dagellulus) < *agellus < ager*
- [*ancillula*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dancillula) < *ancilla < ancula* (Yes, *ancilla* is a diminutive!)
- [*arcellula*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Darcellula) < *arcella < arca*
- [*asellulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dasellulus*) < *asellus < asinus*