# What is oculus a diminutive of?

Tags: vocabulary, diminutive

My Latin teacher has said that *osculum* is the diminutive of *os*, describing the way one puckers one's mouth when kissing, and that the *-culus* ending is a diminutive. So what is *oculus* a diminutive of?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This reminds me of [an earlier question about *angulus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1932/79), and it turned out it was not a diminutive. This might be the case for *oculus* too. I don't know what the answer to this one is, but I am eager to see.

Comment: The *-c-* is part of the PIE root; compare Russian *око*, German *Auge*, etc. But I'm not sure where the *-ul-* comes from, and it certainly does look diminutive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Sihler, *New comparative grammar of Greek and Latin*, the PIE root is **H<sub>3</sub>ek<sup>w</sup>*, 'see'; according to *OLD*, the (theoretical) original Latin form is **oquelos*. Presumably, the *(u)lus* that looks like a diminutive suffix is actually one of the suffixes that are added to verb roots and used to indicate instrument/means (Gildersleeve and Lodge, *Latin grammar* §181.6). Therefore, an *oculus* is 'a means of seeing' (cf. *capulus*, 'handle' [literally, 'a means of taking hold'], *cingulum*, 'girdle' [literally, 'a means of encircling']).

Comment: Are there other Latin words from the same PIE root?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. My understanding is that antiquus is also from this root ('seen before'), but that etymology may be controversial.

Comment: I was curious, so [I asked a separate question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5968/79). Anyway, I am intrigued by this seemingly diminutive suffix having an instrumental function. It never occurred to me, despite the (to me very) familiar example of *pendulum*.

Answer (score 4):

Indo-European *ekʷ (or h³ekʷ) is the source of the word for “eye” in many IE languages (possibly including English, though this is debated). The /l/ suffix is found only in Latin, so it is certainly possible that the Latin form is a diminutive. In this case, ocellus “little eye” would be doubly diminutive, like the words discussed here: [Can there be double diminutives in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/can-there-be-double-diminutives-in-latin?rq=1)