# Are there other Latin words from the same PIE root as oculus?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

In an answer to [the question whether *oculus* is a diminutive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5963/79), cnread told that this word comes from the Proto-Indo-European root **H<sub>3</sub>ek<sup>w</sup>*, "see".
Are there other Latin words from this same root, in particular without the diminutive-looking suffix *-ulus*?
Perhaps *antiquus* (as suggested in a comment)?
I cannot recall any Latin word that looks similar to *oc-* (*oculus* minus the suffix), but of course there may have been bigger sound changes than I can guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NIL](https://www.winter-verlag.de/de/detail/978-3-8253-5359-9/Wodtko_ua_Hg_Nomina_im_Indogerm_Lexikon/) mentions the following:

**atrox**, cf. de Vaan "Probably a derivative of the adj. āter 'black' and the PIE root *h<sub>3</sub>ekw- 'to look', thus 'having a black aspect'."

**ferox**, cf. de Vaan "The adj. fer-ōx may be (one of) the source(s) of the suffix -ōx, if from * [f.]ēro-h<sub>3</sub>kw- 'having a fierce aspect'. This can be disputed, but I see no better source for this suffix."

de Vaan adds one more, **[omen](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=latin&id=la1143)** (?), cf. de Vaan "Proto-Italic okws-mn- 'sighting, omen'?; Proto-Indo-European *h3ekw-s- 'to see' [pr.]."

Comment: Interesting! It never occurred to me that it might appear as a suffix. *Omen* sounds semantically reasonable, too.